# What does "it" mean in these lines?

Tags: pronouns, nouns, dummy-pronouns, antecedents

Can you please help me understand to which noun do **it** [pronoun] refers to in the below sentences?

> He is the murderer. Later **it** was found he is not.

The *it* in the second sentence: " Later **it**...", what does *it* refers to?